# Docker-compose can't connect to Docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

My Postgres DB is running in a Docker container. When container is started, it says it's ready to listen on 5432.
My application container is set to depend on it.

```
    container_name: my_postgres_db
    image: library/postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=localdb
    restart: always
```

The config for app:

```
    container_name: my_test_app
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my_test_app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Based on solutions to the similar questions, I changed the `localhost` in the DB URL to:
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/localdb`

It causes another error = "Unknown host exception". Even if I manage to build app this way, it still doesn't work. Logs say,
`Connection to localhost:5432 refused`
What else am I missing?
Why is it still listening to `localhost:5432` when I obviously changed it to `db:5432` and gradlew clean/build it?

Comment: i assume you have a problem with the networking you can read more https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ and fix it by adding networks instead of exposing the port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the `network_mode` in postgres and app to `host`

```
network_mode: host
```

note that this will ignore the expose option and will use the host network an containers network

Comment: Thank you very much! It did the trick. I set both 'app' and 'db' network_mode in docker-compose.yml to host. I mark your answer as the solution.